# Robot Framework: Two loops iterating different values and writing to expected Excel-rows based on those values

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to demonstrate running two for-loops in Robot Framework for handling different values in those loops and writing values from a list variable to Excel-file.

This simple test for demonstration currently passes and indeed is logging different values from those different loops but is not behaving correctly yet when it comes to writing to Excel file.

I created a list variable @{valueslist} containing 3 values: **Listvalue 0**, **Listvalue 1** and **Listvalue 2**.

The idea would be to write Listvalue 0 to Excel row 5, Listvalue 1 to Excel row 6 and Listvalue 2 to Excel row 7. All rows in column number 0. Sheet in Excel file is named as **Listvalues**.

Why rows 5-7 and not for example 0-2 at the start of Excel file?

Main idea here is to demonstrate different values handled by different loops because values for @{valueslist} and values for Excel rows might differ in a lot of cases later as in this case of demonstrating this. 
It would be easier to write to Excel rows 0-2 because values at that case are same as INDEX in loop range. Actually I got that to work already but now I am trying to test different values for Excel rows (INDEX) and i-values from @{valueslist}.

My problem currently is that expected rows 5-7 in Excel column 0 are being written and saved as new Excel file (saving as new Excel file works) but for every row between 5 and 7 there is Listvalue 2 (value of i being 2 then) being written instead of i-values 0-2 being Listvalue 0, Listvalue 1 and Listvalue 2 so only last value of i gets written to Excel three times and not different value per row as expected so writing part is not working correctly although expected rows are written. Just with wrong values because Listvalue 2 is repeated three times. It has to be that these two loops are not working together as expected.

In Robot I first open an Excel file named Exceldemobase.xls (ExcelLibrary used) used as a template Excel file. Then I have a loop named **Excel Values Main Loop** which has current range of 3 to 6. INDEX value there is correlated to Excel row numbers although not directly with same number values but INDEX is for handling Excel rows.

In Excel Values Main Loop there is another loop included as a keyword named **Excel Values Inner Loop**. That loop is looping ${i} values and i is correlated to index of @{valueslist}. As in that list there are three indexes as 0, 1, 2 (Listvalue 0, Listvalue 1, Listvalue 2 being actual values in that list).

After loops are executed then there is a pause execution popup provided by Dialogs-library used to ask confirmation of user before writing to Excel.

My Robot Framework-code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library           Dialogs
Library           ExcelLibrary

*** Variables ***
${INDEX}          0
${i}              0
@{valueslist}     Listvalue 0    Listvalue 1    Listvalue 2

*** Keywords ***
Excel Values Main Loop
    : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    3    6
    \    Set Suite Variable    ${INDEX}
    \    Excel Values Inner Loop
    \    Log    INDEX value logged in (Excel Values Main Loop) is currently: ${INDEX}

Excel Values Inner Loop
    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    3
    \    Log    Value of i logged in (Excel Values Inner Loop) is currently: ${i}
    \    Log    Listvalue logged in (Excel Values Inner Loop) is currently: @{valueslist}[${i}]
    \    Put String To Cell    Listvalues    0    ${INDEX+1}    @{valueslist}[${i}]
    Set Suite Variable    ${i}

Excel Values Dialog
    Pause Execution    Please press OK to write values to Excel rows

Excel Values 
    [Documentation]    This is expected to write Listvalue 0, Listvalue 1 and Listvalue 2 (only one value per row) from variable @{valueslist} to Excel-rows 5, 6 and 7.
    ...    
    Open Excel    C:/Programming/Robot_Projects/ExcelValuesDemo/Exceldemobase.xls
    Excel Values Main Loop
    Pause Execution    Press OK to save next set of values to Excel
    Save Excel    C:/Programming/Robot_Projects/ExcelValuesDemo/Exceldemofilled.xls
```

**I expected output to be for Excel-rows 5-7 as:**

Listvalue 0 (Expected for Excel row 5)

Listvalue 1 (Expected for Excel row 6)

 
Listvalue 2 (Expected for Excel row 7)

**But actual values were:**

Listvalue 2 (Gets written to Excel row 5)

Listvalue 2 (Gets written to Excel row 6)

Listvalue 2 (Gets written to Excel row 7)

I think that as value of i is 2 at the end of looping in **Excel Values Inner Loop** then that value gets passed to every row but I have not been able to fix these two loops so that there would be this expected output. When I look at log I see that i values 0, 1 and 2 are actually logged so incrementing value of i between 0 and 2 is done during looping as expected but for some reason only the last value as 2 (actual value from list for 2 being Listvalue 2 then) gets written to Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with expected results. Solution was to not use Excel Values Inner Loop included in Excel Values Main Loop but add this line for incrementing value of i directly in that same Main Loop-code:

```
${i}    Evaluate    ${i}+1
```

I don't know if this is possible to be done better way as I noticed that I have to do i-1 in line that handles writing values to Excel:

```
Put String To Cell    Listvalues    0    ${INDEX+1}    @{valueslist}[${i-1}]
```

When doing i-1 then incrementing is started from index 0 in @{valueslist} variable and that leads to correct results. If we were to start incrementing from index 1 there then [${i}] would work directly.

Any way I got expected results now so that is the main thing for me.

I expected output to be for Excel-rows 5-7 as:

Listvalue 0 (Expected for Excel row 5)

Listvalue 1 (Expected for Excel row 6)

Listvalue 2 (Expected for Excel row 7)

Actual values this times were:

Listvalue 0 (Gets written to Excel row 5)

Listvalue 1 (Gets written to Excel row 6)

Listvalue 2 (Gets written to Excel row 7)

```
Excel Values Main Loop
    : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    3    6
    \    Set Suite Variable    ${INDEX}
    \    ${i}    Evaluate    ${i}+1 
    \    Log    INDEX value logged in (Excel Values Main Loop) is currently: ${INDEX}
    \    Put String To Cell    Listvalues    0    ${INDEX+1}    @{valueslist}[${i-1}]
```